# What happens if I overstay in the Schengen area for 1 day but my visa is still valid?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying, visa-expiration

My Schengen visa starts on December 23, 2017 and is valid until January 17, 2018. The duration of stay (as per the visa) is 11 days.

Due to some communication problems, my travel agency booked the flight from December 24, 2017 and the return flight on Jan 5, 2018. That makes the duration of stay to be 13 days.

What can be done? Can anyone help? What are penalties that I may have to face?